# EC2 Cloudformation - userdata using powershell to retrieve powershell scrips from GitHub

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, powershell, github

I have a AWS cloudforamtion - whih build my entire VPC with subnets etc - within this CF builds a windows 2012 server - we want to bootstrap this server under user data so it become a domain controller. All our ps1 scripts are hosted on github. under user data i have entered as below

```
"<powershell>\n",
      "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force\n",
      "Rename-Computer AWSAD10 -restart\n",
      "Start-Sleep -s 100\n",
      "$url = \"https://github.com/username/gittest/blob/testinggit/NewAD.ps1\" \n",
      "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, 'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\NewAD.ps1')\n",
```

the commands to rename the computer works OK - here what is not working the NewAD.PS1 script which is hosted on git - when i run this script on local server all works OK so it promotes to AD by running local however the pull from git is not working - I have also tried:

```
$trueInvoke-WebRequest -Uri "$trueInvoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://raw.github.com/cloudbase/unattended-setup-scripts/master/UpdateAndSysprep.ps1" \n",
```

Any ideas please as I have one week try to figure out how i can do this? and is not much out there how to get this working

Comment: Please clarify "not working". What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: Thank you - rename the computer works  from above srcript - what is not working - is not pulling or retriving the powershell script from github - so the windows server does not get promoted to active directory - in terms of erros not much i can see on ec2config logs - does not tell me much about the user data - i cant find anywhere how i can see the errors.

Comment: cloud-init will print to the console (on boot) - you can tell it to log "output: {all: '| tee -a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log'}"

Comment: Do you have internet connectivity on the instance (public IP address or NATted depending on the subnet)?

Comment: instance is on private network so i have a bastion host which i rdp into it and than rdp from there to the instance. instance go via NAT to outbound and is able to browser the link mentioned above to github

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how I got it working

```
"UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "<powershell>\n",
          "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force\n",
          "Set-Content -Path C:\\OnPremDG.ps1 -Value \"(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/A/1/DA1FDDB8-6DA8-4F50-B4D0-18019591E182/GatewayInstall.exe', 'c:\\GatewayInstall.exe' )`r`n& c:\\GatewayInstall.exe /Q\" -force\n"
            "</powershell>"]]}}
```

Left is a command to run the bloody script :))) (i had it working but lost the command during one of the tests)

Check the log of the scripts at: C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log
The actual script is found in C:\Windows\Temp\UserScript.ps1
You will see the default directory the powershell is at the moment of run is C:\Windows\Temp ... AWS should update their documentation with info regarding this.